# Third Conditional sentences

Tags: conditionals

What will it imply if i say " Wouldn't it have been amazing if you had come home earlier " 
As per my knowledge it simply implies that it wasn't amazing since you didn't come earlier .

Comment: Changed to a positive sentence, it reads as "I would have been amazing, if you had come home earlier."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, though there's an additional implication of *regret* that whatever you're talking about didn't happen. It's a slightly less direct way of saying, "I wish you had come home earlier" or even (depending on the context) "I'm upset that you didn't come home earlier."